# pdo transaction clarification with commit

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

New to using transactions and cannot find a definitive answer on this on the web.  In this example, I realize query1 and query2 both must succeed for anything to be committed to the database and the catch will run if they don't...

Does code entered after commit() (**more code here** in this example) ONLY run if the transaction occurred or will it run regardless?

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    query1

    query2

    $db->commit();

    **more code here**
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
    $db->rollback();

    some error message
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if an exception is thrown, remaining code in the try {} block will not be executed

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be
>   executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.

Comment: I actually already looked at this... perhaps I am thinking too much.  So I can assume, anything after commit will have the newly entered db information from the queries above it, BUT if anything in this code fails the entire try block fails including the commit?

Comment: this does depend on how you are running your queries. not all database code will throw an exception.  That said, if your transaction is configured to throw exceptions on failure then your assumption is correct.  If the transaction is successful you can continue to process the Try {} block. Otherwise everything after the commit attempt is ignored as processing is redirected to the catch block.  If you want something to always be done regardless of exception it should go outside of this try/catch

Comment: But if there is an error inside **more code here** will that fail the entire try block or will the committed queries still take place?

Comment: Well, I just setup some tests... if the transaction fails then nothing after commit happens.  If the transaction succeeds then code after commit does happen... if there is an error in that code the commit still occurs.